# AccessBridgeDebug.h missing?

Tags: java, visual-c++

I'm at my wits end with this Java Bridge, after trying to force it to do what I want in C# I've abandoned the idea and started to stagger my way through Visual C++, however I'm running into constant problems which I'm slowly resolving. Except this one!

I'm missing an include file called AccessBridgeDebug.h.   << **TL:DR read here.**

I can't even compile ANYTHING that uses the includes for AccessBridge because they all reference the debug file, and it just flat out does not come with the package I downloaded, or the one prior to it on the website. Google yields 0 results for the search term "AccessBridgeDebug.h" which has caused me to realise I rely on google far too much.

Please, someone, help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who have the same problem, the solution was fairly simple. The Java Access Bridge 2.0.2 only contains updated files, not the entire package. Furthermore, there is no readily available download link to the 2.0.2 full installer.

To fix it, go here: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-archive-downloads-java-client-downloads.html#accessbridge-2.0.1-oth-JPR (Located `accessbridge-2_0_1-manual_install\src\bridge\src\AccessBridgeDebug.h`)

And download the 2.0.1 full source. All the missing header/c++ files can be found in here.

Comment: That link is no longer active, would you happen to have an updated one?

Comment: Try this GitHub page for [OpenJDK](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/jdk.accessibility/windows/native/common).  Assuming this is for the latest OpenJDK release.